# Dynamodb in Python Tornado Framework

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, tornado

Is it possible to use dynamodb in the tornado async flow using @gen.coroutine and yield?

```
from tornado import gen
import aioboto3

@gen.coroutine
def test():
    data = {}
    session = aioboto3.Session()
    with (yield session) as session:
        dynamo_resource = yield session.rosource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1',verify=False)
        table = yield dynamo_resource.Table('sample_table')
        result = yield table.query(
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('user_id').eq('user001')
            )
    for index, item in enumerate(result['Items']):
        data[f"item{index}"] = item
    print(data)
```

i tried the above code, but it's not working, can someone help me if this is possible to use dynamodb in tornado async flow?

Using the normal async and await it is working, but i wanted to check if it works for tornado async flow also

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `yield` instead of the newer `async`/`await`?

Comment: It won't work because `yield` works on a generator, and `await` works on an awaitable. What I mean is, if `dynamo_resource.Table('sample_table')` is returning an awaitable, you can't use a `yield` statement on it.